# J2ME: How to inspect application's crash which doesn't throw any visible exception?

Tags: java-me, crash

I develop multimedial application within the Java ME platform. It's application usable for voice recording and after replaying. 
I have treated many pieces of code by try/catch block, which should provide an alert in the case an exception occured. The application works fine on java emulator but on Symbian phone it seems fine but the application crashes after some minutes of working without any message and also without any system message. It just falls down, the application is abruptly terminated.

Is there any way how to find where's the problem? I've tried to surround all big pieces of code by try/catch block but the result is same.

Thanks for you advice

Comment: Perhaps the phone mobile device has not enough memory !?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Symbian on device debugger](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-42DE9C15-99C4-42BA-A436-8595AF265CE7.html) or [tracing](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-9011BDA6-C15E-455C-8979-D70749A350AF.html) on the device to determine the exact location of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can log to file on the device every step that you make before it stops and after like "I'm doing XYZ" with timestamps and other stuff like variables values then try to figure out what is going on. Of course You'll get only stuff that happened before crash but it can give You some new info.